# System.Drawing and Garbage Collection

Tags: .net, asp.net, memory-management

As some may be aware, I recently posted about high memory usage on my website and I have an idea that my thumbnailer may have something to do with this as I am not actively disposing of the instance when it has been used due to my misunderstanding how it works.

I am now looking at my code for the thumbnailer and would like some advice on when something would actually need disposing of, is it ONLY when you create a new instance of an object?

Like:

```
Target := System.Drawing.Bitmap.Create(Trunc(Width), Trunc(Height));
MyImage := Target.FromFile(PhotoPath);
```

So, my question would be, do I need to dispose of both Target and MyImage to make sure the GC does what it needs to do properly?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `Create` method in `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. What is it exactly that you are calling?

Comment: The code is in Delphi (our software at work is written in Delphi so the web version of it is as well), equivelent in C# would be System.Drawing.Bitmap Target = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Width, Height);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this blog post on MSDN: [.NET Memory Leak: To dispose or not to dispose, that’s the 1 GB question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/net-memory-leak-to-dispose-or-not-to-dispose-thats-the-1-gb-question). The recommendation appears to be that you should be disposing.

Comment: Thanks for the link, printed and read. Have been learning alot from Tess over the past couple of days. This post answered all my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would, as a general policy, turn the question on its head:

> Is there any reason I should not disposed of these particular objects

If the class implements `IDisposable`, it's your job to dispose of it.

In many cases though the object doesn't do much when you dispose of it, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't call Dispose on it. If you ever upgrade to a new .NET runtime version, that might've changed.

Ok, let me clarify what I said here.

Of course I'm not saying you should just call `Dispose` on any and all objects that implement `IDisposable`. The question is, *is it your object*. If you constructed it, it is your responsibility.

If you were given the object, assume it isn't yours, unless you specifically require the object to be given, and not just loaned out to you temporarily.

And of course there are other exceptions as well, but *as a general rule*, objects you own that implement `IDisposable`, dispose of them when you're done.

Comment: But there are exceptions to every rule. The Graphics object you get passed in a OnPaint Function should not be disposed. The best rule of thumb is "If you got it from a =, dispose. If it was a parameter passed to you in a function, leave it alone"

Comment: It all has to do with ownership. The question is 'I'm the owner (usually the creator) of this object'.

Answer (score 2):

`Image` implements disposable. You should dispose it when you're done with it. With images it is very important to dispose them. They allocate just a few bytes of managed memory, but reference a large block of native memory.

Comment: Upped for the memory allocation point; it seems (from my reading) that native memory seems to be the big culprit for high memory and images so this explains why. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both calls result in the creation of new `Bitmap` objects, so you need to dispose them when you are done with them.

You should also be aware that there are other graphics related objects that you might be using that also needs to be disposed, like `Graphics`, `Brush` and `Font`.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, Dispose the IDisposables you have created. Certainly in the GDI+

Preferably in a `using() {}` block.

```
using (Pen p = new Pen(Colors.Blue))  // Dispose this pen
{
    Brush b = Brushes.Green; // but not this Brush
    ....
}
```

Comment: Would love to but haven't managed to find an equivelent in Delphi ... can't wait for the C# rewrite of the engine :)

Comment: Delphi 8 - Delphi2006 did have Using blocks, didn't they? I don't know the Chrome based versions. But using is just short-hand for try-finally, you do have that.