# Real asp.net memory leak or is visual studio to blame

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks

I've been working on a small aspx website all week; this morning I noticed that my local instance was running extremely slowly.  When checked in task manager, my webdev.WebServer40.exe process had a ~1.2GB working set.  After restarting visual studio and running the site for about an hour afterwards the memory total is only about 100MB.

Is this an indication that serverside code is leaking memory somewhere, or is the webserver process just inefficient about cleaning up junk that accumulates over dozens of rebuilds?

Comment: Overuse of the session state, perhaps?

Comment: @TimRogers how'd I check?  My background's been almost entirely in desktop before I was assigned to do a round of bugfixes on the site.

Comment: Search the code for `Session["someKey"] = someValue` and see what's being added. If there are big things (datasets, images, etc) then you have a problem.

Comment: I'm at a total loss as to why this question would be closed.

Comment: @TimRogers there were one hit for `Session[` that was an assignment and it was only storing an email address; so it looks like I'm clear on that front.

Comment: What sort of additional information would I need to have my question reopened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's something in your code. The webserver itself isn't likely a problem, as .NET developers all over the world would have noticed it and raised a stink by now.

There's really not enough information here for us to tell you what the exact problem is.  You'll need to look into it yourself or get someone who's more familiar with ASP.NET to help you. However, general guidelines are available online.

See this article for guidance for .NET in general:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813.aspx

or

[Quick things to check when you experience high memory levels in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893660)

or (darn, this makes the quesiton a duplicate.)  here: [ASP.NET Website Memory Usage quite high](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405557/asp-net-website-memory-usage-quite-high)

Comment: Thanks, I think I found a winner in your last link.  Lots of event subscribing, zero cleanup.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Sorry I wasn't able to be more specific, but I'm glad you found what you were looking for.

Comment: well I found something.  I'll need a few days to see if it was the primary problem or not.  As for specificity I wanted to make sure visual studios bloat/leakage didn't affect any processes it was spawning before i started hunting down large additional amounts of info.